# Best way to create a custom view with only one child

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I want to create a UI component that offers a very limited set of public methods.
It will include inside it just one regular UI component.

One way to achieve it is:

```
<LinearLayout>
  <VideoView...>
```

But there are two drawbacks:

1. there's a useless ViewGroup (the LinearLayout)
2. I cannot pass the layouting attributes to the inner component.

Another way would be inherited the included UI component. But I don't want to expose the public methods of it.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Why you cannot pass attributes to inner component?

Comment: Because AFAIK if I use a given layout (let's say LinearLayout) I need to pass LinearLayout to the VideoView. And maybe the component is put into another type of layout.

Comment: Yep, but you can check instance of the `ViewGroup` or `View`...

Comment: Yes, I guess that I can check each possible type in setLayout and set children accordingly. I'll do that if no other option exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am mistaken, and don't figure out your question, but anyway
try to use `<merge>` tag.

```
<?xml ...>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <VideoView... />
</merge>
```

And in your CustomView inflate it and add as child:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this, true);
```

Comment: What class should my component inherit?

Comment: any successor of ViewGroup